# Populating kendo-tree using from Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik

I am in Angular environment using Kendo. All I want to do is following:

1. Take Json
2. Produce Kendo tree using it

I have tried it with simple data and it seems to work fine. But this time I have somewhat complex data and it seems like it does not work well with complex Json. I have been trying to have it render Json but it seems like it keeps on thinking and never comes back. I have created a sample Dojo for reference:

http://dojo.telerik.com/EdOqE

I am not sure what am I doing wrong but it just does not seem to work. Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you have controll over the resultant json, because you'll have to change it a little to fit the TreeView's expected format. Check this out:

```
{
    "items": [{ // Projects
        "Id": 0,
        "Name": "Your Example Project",
        "CreatedOn": "",
        "hasChildren": true,
        "items": [{ // Analyses
            "Id": 0,
            "Name": "1.0 - Your Example Run",
            "CreatedOn": "",
            "hasChildren": true,
            "items": [{ // Samples
                "Id": 0,
                "Name": "Sample 1",
                "hasChildren": false,
                "Description": "ample frample sample"
            }, {
                "Id": 0,
                "Name": "Sample 2",
                "hasChildren": false,
                "Description": null
            }]
        }]
    }]
};
```

The above json is what I did to work in the widget. First of all, the collection properties were renamed to `items`. All of them, in all levels. With that, kendo will know how property it should deal with. A `hasChildren` property was added to let it know when it has to show the expand icon. Otherwise it will show the expand option even if the item doesn't haves any children. So user clicks it and get an empty result.

This is the widget initialization options:

```
{
    dataSource: new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({ 
        data: things,
        schema: {
            data: "items"
        }
    }),
    dataTextField: "Name"
};
```

With `schema.data` I tell which property kendo will deal as the collection item. The dataSource expects an array, but if you give him an object, you have to set this property. If it was an array, then kendo would look for `item` property of each child for default. `dataTextField` is the name of the property it will use as the label.

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EdOqE/4)

[Here is another demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EdOqE/6) with the data as an array. No need to set `schema.data`.

**Update:**

I was afraid you would say that. Yes, there is a way to deal with the data if you can't change it in the server-side. You have to intercept the data at the [`schema.parse()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.parse) method and change the resultant data object property to `items`, so then the widget will understand:

```
schema: {
    data: "items",
    parse: function(data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty("Projects")) {
            return { items: data.Projects };
        }
        else if (data.hasOwnProperty("Analyses")) { 
            return { items: data.Analyses };
        }
        else if (data.hasOwnProperty("Samples")) { 
            return { items: data.Samples };
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EdOqE/10)

Every node when opened will call `parse` with `items` collection as `data` parameter. You have to return a new object with the property name as `items` instead of `Projects`, `Analysis` or `Samples`.

---

I forgot you can't touch the data, so can't add `hasChildren` property as well. Then you have to add a tiny logic into `parse` to set those properties in each level, otherwise the *expand* icon would not appear:

```
schema: {
    data: "items",
    parse: function(data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty("Projects")) {

            data.Projects.forEach(p => {
                p.hasChildren = false;

                if (p.hasOwnProperty("Analyses")) {
                    p.hasChildren = true;
                }
            });

            return { items: data.Projects };
        }
        else if (data.hasOwnProperty("Analyses")) { 

            data.Analyses.forEach(a => {
                a.hasChildren = false;

                if (a.hasOwnProperty("Samples")) {
                    a.hasChildren = true;
                }
            });

            return { items: data.Analyses };
        }
        else if (data.hasOwnProperty("Samples")) { 
            return { items: data.Samples };
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EdOqE/11)

It is ugly, I know. But get used to Kendo, it is the it goes with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It was really helpful. However, my incoming json is from an external service. I do not have control over the elements to name them 'Item' instead of what they are originally named. Is there any way to define schema which supports original json?

Comment: This is just amazing. Thank you so much for your detailed and extremely helpful answer.

Comment: Just for curiosity. The idea of renaming each element as item is for simplicity or is it because Kendo-Tree view simply just does not support the original names to exist?

Comment: @CoffeeBean it supports only one property to contain the children. In this case I named it as `items`(which is the default name, actually). That is why you have to set all properties with children array with the same name. I think it would be really easy to kendo staff to implement something like `children: ["Projects", "Analyses", "Samples"]` so the widget assumes array pos #1 for node level #1 and so on.. but, they like to make us suffer sometimes. =)

Comment: Thank you. This was really helpful.